# Multiple Index Match formula slows down excel sheet performance

Tags: excel

I have a large dataset that expands by time, could reach 100k entries if not more. and I'm using a combination of Index and Match to view a mini-table from another table based on the key element that indicates the needed data.

My data exists in a table in a separate sheet, what I need to do is whenever I type in A1 for example, a specific serial "AA1", it should look up for the sheet table where the column named "serial" is, and return with all matching outcome with that serial.

The issue is this process should be multiplied in 15 columns over 100k rows.

and here's the formula I use for each column/row:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet!$A:$A,SMALL(IF((Sheet!$O:$O=!$A$1),ROW(Sheet!$A:$A)-ROW(Sheet!$A$2)+2),ROWS($1:1))),"")
```

The reason why I use the full column index "$A:$A" is because as I said earlier, it's a very large dataset and it is expandable over time. if I made it $A1:$A100000 , it will process 100k entries even if there are no values past-50k for example, which will indeed slow down the sheet performance.
but using full column became even worse, the sheet is VERY SLOW updating between each element. and I need the sheet to calculate automatically, not manually. Please advise if there's a better solution or a better integration to view data based on key elements.

Here's an example of my sheet, what I want to do is whenever I type 15, the second table auto generates the co-related data from the other sheet with the key element "15", to be filled accordingly across A, B, C and D.

Imagine the same process over 100k entries, and instead of A, B, C and D; it's from A to Z. literally.

[image]

[image]

Comment: From your explanation alone, I can't figure out what you're actually doing. Perhaps you could explain it more fully (ideally with small sample pictures of both the source and results sheets).

Comment: @Spinner Added dear.

Comment: If you're using a version that supports Dynamic Arrays, you could do this more efficiently with `Filter`

Comment: The examples don't match your formula: The formula refers to column O in 'Sheet'. Yet your examples doesn't use column O and doesn't a sheet name Sheet.

Comment: Why not just convert your source data to an Excel table? That way you solve the last row issue. What's more, you could simply add a slicer to that table to allow the user to filter the table, instead of your current unnecessarily  resource-heavy set-up.

Comment: As @Jos Woolley said re using a table. Tables naturally grow when you add data. In formulas you reference the whole column of data and any new rows are automatically used in formulas.

Comment: I replaced the cell ref with table header but it does not work what so ever. It has to have a cell range even if its A:A instead of table header name in order to work. Any help?